# Using Listagg to get only one row when joining data from 4 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

I have data in 4 tables and want to have following data in one row:
              table1.*,table2.*,table3.*,table4.*

I am using inner join to do that but table4 has 2 rows with the same foreign key so I get two rows instead of one. I want to use Listagg to solve this and join both records into one, but I am not exactly sure how to do that. I have only seen samples where you select specific columns, not *.

Comment: Did you look at the [tag:listagg] tag info? I have given a link to the documentation as well as the usage with an example.

Comment: Please show us your expected input and expected result in a tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't seen examples using `*` because you can't do that, at least with the table that has the column you want to aggregate. You don't want to group by the column you're aggregating as that default's the purpose. There is no way to exclude a column from a `*` list, so if you did, say:

```
select t4.*, listagg(col2) within group (order by col2)
from t4
group by t4.col1;
```

then you would get "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" because `col2` isn't in the group-by; and if you included it then you'd get one row back for each unique value for `col2` anyway, rather than a list of values.

You have to expand the column list:

```
select t4.col1, listagg(t4.col2) within group (order by t4.col2)
from t4
group by t4.col1;
```

You *could* still use `t1.*` etc. for your joined version, but since you have to list all the columns from all the tables explicitly in the group-by clause anyway (`*` isn't allowed there, only in the select-list) it doesn't really gain you much:

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*, t4.col1,
  listagg(t4.col2) within group (order by t4.col2)
from t1
join ... 
group by t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, ..., t4.col1;
```

You might as well do:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, ..., t4.col1,
  listagg(t4.col2) within group (order by t4.col2)
from t1
join ... 
group by t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col1, ..., t4.col1;
```

It's generally better practice to list all the columns explicitly in the select-list anyway, to avoid surprises - you won't see problems if the columns are in a different order in the tables in different environments (which shouldn't really happen anyway under proper source control) and the query result won't change if a column is added to a table. `select *` is useful for ad hoc queries but shouldn't really be used in real code.

Comment: OK, I understand your concerns. But I am building this query just to export some data into CSV to use in further processing and there are a lot of columns so I am really trying to avoid typing them all. I don't have GROUP BY at the end currently, and maybe I won't need it. My query currently looks like this: SELECT LISTAGG(agg_column, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY agg_column) FROM( SELECT DISTINCT t1.*,t2.*,t3.*,t4.agg_column from t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON ... INNER JOIN t3 ON ... INNER JOIN t4 ON ... WHERE xxxx). If I modify beginning to SELECT *,LISTAGG(agg_column, ',')... of course it does not work

Comment: But I need to have all columns in result, not just agg_column

Comment: @Tians - but you don't want all the columns; you want all of them *except* `agg_column`. If you include any non-aggregate columns (which you want to do) then you have to have a `group by` clause, also including all colums except `agg_column`. (Or you could use an analytic version, but then you have to partition by all of those instead). You have to type them all. Or you could generate them from the data dictionary but that sems more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: OK, you are right, there is probably no other solution than to write them all.

Comment: @Tians - if you're just trying to avoid typing them all out, and typos, you can [get them from the data dictionary](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8e40/1), as I said before; and then just copy and paste that into your real query.